# jQuery is working in IE but not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I wrote a simple php form and validate it using jQuery.
Surprisingly the validation is working correctly in IE version "11.0.9600.18163"
But in Chrome version "55.0.2883.87" its not working. Meaning the form can be submitted with no values.

PHP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Event Certificate System</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="enStyle.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- jQuery Validation Plugin 
hosted by Google API -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="addEvent-validation.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"><img id="all" src="img/enHeader.png" alt="Event Certificate System"/></div>
  <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li class="current"><a href="AddEvent.php"><span>Add Event</span></a></li>
      <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="addAttendance.php"><span>Add Attendance</span></a></li>
      <li class="cust"><a href="sendCertificate.php"><span>Send Certificate</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <div id="content">
    <h3 class="custom">Add Event Form</h3>
    <form action="addEvent.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addEvent-form" novalidate>
      <div class="formLayout">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Event Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="etitle" dir="ltr"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="required">
          <label>Event Date</label>
          <input type="text" name="edate" id="datepicker">
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" class="styled_button"/>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"> <img id="bottom" src="img/footer.png" alt="Event Certificate System"/> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery is:

```
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};
    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
    $("#addEvent-form").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            etitle: 
            {
            required: true,
            },
            edate:
            {
            required: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            etitle: 
            {
            required: "Enter Event Title",
            },
            edate:
            {
            required: "Enter Event Date",
            },
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
                }
            });
}}
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Try to remove the `enctype` to see if it works.

Comment: it didn't solve it

Comment: Can you create a `fiddle`?

Comment: @OffirPe'er Here it's: https://jsfiddle.net/Somayah/sjzr4gpx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a working **[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/jmvPwD6viGd4uPhoOJfJ?p=preview)** for you.

You had a few problems in your code that are not related to the type of browser you were using.
There were a few redundant `,` and there was a mix with `{` over the document ready.

The plugin you are using is **[Jquery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)**.

 Good luck.

Comment: Thank you I learned my lesson. However, I think my mistake was loading two different jQuery libs versions.